# Can I use multiple reset-timer function in one procedure in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to build 4 classrooms in Netlogo and students will be entering the 4 classrooms one by one according to their random entry-time. So in my go procedure, I will have to use multiple (2 times) reset-timer for the students to enter the 4 classrooms one by one. But the students of one classroom are all entering in 0 minutes. Why is this happening?

```
to go

  reset-timer
  tick
  create-students-classroom
  move-students

  reset-timer
  move-studentsB

  reset-timer
  move-studentsC

  reset-timer
  move-studentsD 
  wait 1
  move-student-out
  if ticks >= 1 [stop]

 end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look a [the dictionary entry to `reset-timer`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reset-timer), you'll see the following warning:

> Note that the timer is different from the tick counter. The timer measures elapsed real time in seconds; the tick counter measures elapsed model time in ticks.

I think that the approach that you have tried so far mixes up "ticks" and "real time", which will lead to all sorts of problems down the road.

In an agent-based model, you should really be focusing on ticks, not real-time. Real-time depends on the speed of your computer, and is pretty much meaningless in the context of a simulation. "Ticks," by contrast are really conceptual "model steps" and they're the relevant unit in almost all cases.

By convention, in NetLogo, we run the `go` procedure, once per tick. This is why the skeleton of a NetLogo model should almost always look like this:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ; some setup code goes here
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ; some code goes here
  tick
end
```

I don't know enough about what you're trying to achieve to give you a complete solution, but something like this could be a starting point for a tick-based model:

```
breed [ classrooms classroom ]
breed [ students student ]

students-own [ entry-time ]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape classrooms "square"
  set-default-shape students "person"
  ask n-of 4 patches [ sprout-classrooms 1 ]
  ask n-of 50 patches with [ not any? classrooms-here ] [ sprout-students 1 ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if all? students [ any? classrooms-here ] [
    ask students [ show entry-time ]
    stop ; stop when all students are in class
  ]
  ask one-of classrooms [
    ask one-of students with [ not any? classrooms-here ] [
      move-to myself
      set entry-time ticks
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

I won't explain all the code in details, but I would suggest trying to understand what it does by running through it one tick at time and looking up the primitives you don't know in the dictionary. Even if it's not exactly what you're after, it should give you understand how to build a tick-based model and give you some ideas about how to approach your own problem.

Comment: thanks that was really helpful. But what I am trying to do is calculate the energy that is consumed in a classroom in KWh. Each classroom will have a set of Fans Lights and ACs and according to where the students sit that particular fan and light will turn on. From which the overall power can be calculated.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. And it sounds like a really cool project. But still, the point stands: you shouldn't be using the timer, even if you want to represent "real time". Instead, you should decide that one tick equals a specific time duration (e.g., one second) and base your calculations on that.