# How can I stop the timer of Netlogo for few minutes?

Tags: netlogo

I am doing a netlogo simulation where I have to stop the timer for few seconds. How can I stop the timer for few seconds. I am a beginner.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to stop the timer? It is very unusual to use a timer at all - instead, you would normally increment the clock (using `tick` command) to move through time steps that represent some real world amount of time.

Comment: are you talking about `timer`, or are you talking about `ticks`? the former is time in the real world, the latter is time within simulation

Comment: I see you're getting good advice on this over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57413244/can-i-use-multiple-reset-timer-function-in-one-procedure-in-netlogo

Comment: What I am doing is I am simulating a classroom from which I can find out the amount of total energy in KWh that is being used due to fans. lights and ACs when students come in. So when student sits on a chair, the corresponding light and fans will turn on. and the energy corresponding to the fan and light will be calculated. Thus i need to stop the timer for a few seconds. As the students will enter according to different random timer times.